# Big O notation : limited input

Tags: python, big-o

As an exercise, I am trying to set Monte Carlo Simulation on a chosen ticker symbol.

```
from numpy.random import randint
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from math import log

# ticker symbol
ticker_input = "AAPL"  # change

# start day + endday for Yahoo Finance API, 5 years of data
start_date = date.today()
end_date = start_date - timedelta(days=1826)

# retrieve data from Yahoo Finance
data = yf.download(ticker_input, end_date,start_date)
yf_data = data.reset_index()

# dataframe : define columns
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', "ln_change", 'open_price', 'random_num'])

open_price = []
date_historical = []

for column in yf_data:
    open_price = yf_data["Open"].values
    date_historical = yf_data["Date"].values  

# list order: descending
open_price[:] = open_price[::-1]
date_historical[:] = date_historical[::-1]

# Populate data into dataframe
for i in range(0, len(open_price)-1):
    # date
    day = date_historical[i]
    
    # ln_change
    lnc = log(open_price[i]/open_price[i+1], 2)

    # random number
    rnd = randint(1, 1258)

    # op = (open_price[i]) open price
    df.loc[i] = [day, open_price[i], lnc, rnd]
```

I was wondering how to calculate Big O if you have e.g. nested loops or exponential complexity but have a limited input like one in my example, maximum input size is 1259 instances of float number. Input size is not going to change.

How do you calculate code complexity in that scenario?

Comment: Where do you say you have nested loops? I don't see them. Maybe you just didn't indent the code properly? The way it's written right now the complexity appears linear to me. If the second loop were indented (as I believe was intended) then the complexity is O(N*M) where N is the number of columns in the df and M is the number of records per column.

Comment: Big O complexity is rather pointless if there's no variables affecting the execution size. The execution time will be constant, it's effectively O(1), unless the number of inputs varies between 0 and 1259, in which case you have your `n` and you can estimate limiting behaviour and give a Big O.

Comment: @pavel Maybe I wasn't clear, but I've put e.g. in the question. My example is limited input, but I was wondering how you define code complexity if you have e.g. factorial complexity with limited input. Big O is something new to me so the question was how to define code complexity when unlimited input can not be presumed, I only have 1259 size input and that will not change.

Comment: @Grismar I didn't know that constant becomes O(n) when limited input varies. Thank you.

Comment: As @Grismar pointd out, if your input size never changes, it doesn't really make sense to talk about Big O complexity since the execution time will always be the same, i.e. independent of the size of the input. Big O complexity specifically refers to the relationship between code execution and the size of the input.

Comment: @pavel I understand that, but what I didn't understood is what if I have fixed input of let say 10.000 items, and my code is pretty complex, that kind of scenarios. Every video I watched on YT on Big O doesn't go deep into notation exceptions. I am trying to understand the essence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of points of view. Both ways of seeing it are technically correct. The question is: What information do you wish to convey to the reader?

Consider the following code:

```
quadraticAlgorithm(n) {
    for (i <- 1...n)
        for (j <- 1...n)
            doSomethingConstant();
}
quadraticAlgorithm(1000);
```

The function is clearly *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. And yet the program will always run in the same, constant time, because it just contains one function call with *n=1000*. It is still perfectly valid to refer to the function as *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. And we can refer to the program as *O(1)*.

But sometimes the boundaries are not that clear. Then it is up to you to choose if you wish to see it as an algorithm with a time complexity as some function of *n*, or as a piece of constant code that runs in *O(1)*. The importance is to make it clear to the reader how you define things.

Comment: Thank you. The more info I get the more I understand it. So it is not exact science, but a way to explain code complexity in terms of time and space using notation rules and subjective assessment. So, in your example with limited input data notation could be defined as O(1) even if it looks as O(n^2), so I guess upper input bound that would define code as quadratic (still limited input) would be subjectively defined.

Comment: @Jovica Exactly. The key is making it clear what you mean. And, conversely, if it's a homework or a test, to guess what the professor means ;)